# jqGrid: no such method: resetSelection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I'm using strongly typed helper for jqGrid - [Lib.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc)

I can't force jqGrid to sort my data. When I click on arrow in the header, I get the following error in Firebug:

> uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: resetSelection

also when I click on cell in the row I get:

> uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: setSelection

This is my js code:

```
@{
      var grid = new Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridHelper<ViolationViewModel>("products",
      dataType: Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridDataTypes.Json,
      methodType: Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
      pager: true,
      rowsNumber: 5,
      sortingName: "Id",
      sortingOrder: Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
      url: Url.Action("Violation", "Cabinet"),
      viewRecords: true,
      rowsList: new List<int>() { 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100 },
      autoWidth: true,
      loadOnce: true,
      rowsNumbers: true
    );
}
```

I'm using `loadOnce` option.

This code in action:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Violation(JqGridRequest request)
        {
            JqGridResponse response = new JqGridResponse()
                {
                    TotalRecordsCount = 7
                };
            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord<ViolationViewModel>("1", new ViolationViewModel
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Test1"
                }));

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord<ViolationViewModel>("2", new ViolationViewModel
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Test2"
            }));

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord<ViolationViewModel>("3", new ViolationViewModel
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Test3"
            }));

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord<ViolationViewModel>("4", new ViolationViewModel
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "Test4"
            }));

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord<ViolationViewModel>("5", new ViolationViewModel
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "Test5"
            }));

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord<ViolationViewModel>("6", new ViolationViewModel
            {
                Id = 6,
                Name = "Test6"
            }));

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord<ViolationViewModel>("7", new ViolationViewModel
            {
                Id = 7,
                Name = "Test7"
            }));

            return new JqGridJsonResult() { Data = response };
        }
```

Comment: Looks like client side issue, are you sure you have referenced all the required jqGrid JavaScript files?

Comment: @tpeczek: I have referenced `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and `grid.locale-en.js` files. I'm using the last version of jqGrid and jQuery (1.9). There are was some problems, because `.browser` function have been removed from jQuery and I include `jQuery Migrate Plugin`. Can you test it?

Comment: Well I'm afraid jQuery version 1.9 might be the issue here. jqGrid will not support it till next major release --> http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1026. The jQuery Migrate Plugin might not be enough. I will try to test in this set up later, but I'm almost sure it is nothing in Lib.Web.Mvc.

Comment: @tpeczek: I have found the error. All works fine with `jQuery 1.9` and `Migrate` plugin. The view where jqGrid is located loaded via ajax as partial view. All jqGrid's files are included in this view. I have move this files to layout file and all works fine. I don't know why. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @tpeczek: and one more question. How can I specify `ignoreCase` when toolbar search is enabled?

Comment: It seems that the JavaScript from partial haven't been evaluated early enough - I would need to see entire page flow in order to same something correct. If it comes to `ignoreCase` there is a request for this feature: http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/workitem/12711. It has been implemented in alpha package and will be part of next release.